# Выравнивание текста по левой и правой границе виджета

Tags: android, вёрстка

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в SDK атрибут, выравнивающий текст по правому и по левому краю одновременно, чтобы он занимал все выделенное пространство?

Вот это я имею в виду.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня пока так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android не поддерживает выравнивание по ширине. Воспользуйтесь сторонними библиотеками.

https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview

https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

https://github.com/programingjd/justified

и т.д.

P.S. Можно использовать WebView как альтернативный вариант